# How do I open the default mail client and create an email?

Tags: c#, email, client

I want to open the default mail client registering on Windows and create an email with an attachment.

The behaviour is just like when you right click on a file, the Send to -> Mail Recipient. Or when you compressing a folder and select 'compress and email' on the context menu.

I have tried:

1. mailto:xxx@example.com, which doesn't accept attachment.
2. MAPI, which works well when the outlook is shutdown, but doesn't work when the outlook is currently working. Do you know how to make it work?

Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of your mail client, try to add `&attach="C:\some_file.txt` to the end of `mailto:xxx@xxx.com`.  This should add an attachment when the mail client opens.  If `attach` does not work, try `attachment` in stead.  I wonder if you can't add both.